# Incorrectly crop the picture

Tags: python, django

Got code for crop image

```
x = int(request.POST.get('x'))
y = int(request.POST.get('y'))
h = int(request.POST.get('h'))
w = int(request.POST.get('w'))

user = RegModel.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

user.cropping.delete(save=True)

picture_copy = ContentFile(user.image.read())
new_picture_name = user.image.name.split("/")[-1]
user.cropping.save(new_picture_name, picture_copy)

image = Image.open(user.cropping)
cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y))
resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
resized_image.save(user.cropping.path)
```

In my template jquery set parameters for crope image x, y, width, height and that i send it to server. Jquery show for me how will look croped image but after croped image on server backend imge look incorrectly. Where my falt?

Comment: What do you mean by it's incorrect?

Comment: Black fields appear and are not cut out properly

Comment: Can you upload a picture to show us

Comment: sure http://imgur.com/a/YGwCB

Answer (score 0):

[`image.crop`()](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.crop) expects a bounding box tuple,

> The box is a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate.

Currently, assuming positive x and y, the last two elements of the bounding box, w + x and h + y, are larger than the image dimensions! This is why you are getting black edges on the right and the bottom of your picture!

Depending on the desired outcome and how exactly you get your input x and y, you could try (x, y, w-x, w-y), or perhaps ( x/2, y/2, w - x/2, h - y/2).